# What is the simplest way to book a rental car in Tahiti?

Tags: online-resources, car-rentals, tahiti

I've been using major sites like rentalcars, expedia and multi-search engines kayak, skyscanner, momondo everywhere else, but for Tahiti, they don't return any results. I can see the usual Hertz, Avis etc located there, any idea why they don't appear in any of the major sites?

I can see they have their local page and long forms to fill to request a booking, which feels like a lot of hassle, while the travel sites make it really easy.

Is there any search site to see the availability and book a car there online, without having to deal with those tedious forms and waiting for them to reply?

Comment: I just used Kayak to look for cars in Papeete (from April 21st to April 27th), which showed me bookings via Expedia.  I don't know why you are not seeing the same thing.

Comment: I forgot to add that I then clicked on the Expedia links and once on Expedia itself, started the process of booking the car.

Comment: Rentalcars didn't have any results for me, but Expedia did.  [Example Expedia search](https://www.expedia.com/carsearch?locn=Papeete%2C%20French%20Polynesia%20(PPT-Tahiti%20Faaa%20Intl.)&pickupIATACode=PPT&olat=-17.55951&olon=-149.609724&dpln=5525584&loc2=&returnIATACode=&dlat=&dlon=&drid1=&d1=2024-2-19&d2=2024-2-23&date1=2/19/2024&date2=2/23/2024&time1=1030AM&time2=1030AM&aarpcr=off)

Comment: @PeterM It seems Expedia.com indeed returns results but not Expedia.ie I was using, neither their UK site. Problem with their US page Expedia.com is that their deals don't seem to include the mandatory liability insurance, at least it is not mentioned in the conditions.